# Perform an action in Django after a period of time?

Tags: python, django, time, backend

I'm working in a project with Django and I want to remove a register from the DataBase after a period of time (1 week after being created). Is there any way that I can do that?

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: Have you looked into [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) ?

Comment: A SQLite for Development. I want not just delete that element. I also want to send a "notification" to the user that his "article" has been deleted. I have the methods to send the notification, i just want to know how call that action after 1 week after the article was created.